# How to get the URL of the calling application in my REST service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, networking

I am trying to implement a google analytics like service. This service will be called by client side JS embedded in different applications.

In my service, I want to extract the URL of the caller application. Is there any way in which I can extract this information in my service rather than have the client side JS send it (client side is less preferable because of data safety issues) ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question completely but generally you can read caller URL from HTTP referrer header

Comment: Yes but it can be spoofed by writing custom scripts right (by setting the referrer header of the request)? Do you know if there is any fool proof way of getting the caller URL

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:
[image: URL of the caller]

For this add HttpServletRequest request in API argument and try this

```
String uri = request.getScheme() + "://" +   // "http" + "://
             request.getServerName() +       // "localhost"
             ":" + request.getServerPort() + // ":" + "8080"
             request.getRequestURI() +       // "/employee"
            (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" +
             request.getQueryString() : ""); // "?" + "lastname=Kumar&age=30"
```